# Deploy Pyramid application with Nginx + Waitress

Tags: nginx, pyramid

I tried to deploy my application on VPS server where I already have two web applications, on the same IP address, but served with Apache and actually run on PHP. So, what I wanna do is to run Pyramid application on the same IP using Nginx and Pserve ( I'm not sure about what is that Waitress for, but I have couple of lines in my configuration file ).

My **production.ini** config:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:gsoft

jinja2.directories =
    gsoft:core/templates
    gsoft:admin/templates
    gsoft:admin/cat/templates
    gsoft:admin/post/templates
    gsoft:admin/page/templates
    gsoft:admin/settings/templates

pyramid.reload_templates = false
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_tm

mongo_uri = mongodb://localhost:27017/gsoft

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = gsoft-domain.com
port = 5000

[loggers]
keys = root, gsoft

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console

[logger_gsoft]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = gsoft

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

and Nginx domain config, **/etc/nginx/sites-available/gsoft-domain.com** :

```
upstream gsoft-domain.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}

server {

    server_name  gsoft-domain.com;
    charset     utf-8

    access_log  /root/gsoft-domain.com/logs/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   60s;
        proxy_send_timeout      90s;
        proxy_read_timeout      90s;
        proxy_buffering         off;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
        proxy_pass              http://gsoft-domain.com;
        proxy_redirect          off;
    }
}
```

I don't actually understand all the lines of this, it's from official Pyramid recipes in documentation.

In nginx config file **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** I don't have nothing special, so I realize do not publish it here, because I didn't change the line there after nginx has been installed.

When I try to run pserve with command:

```
root@gsoft:~/gsoft# pserve production.ini --reload
Starting subprocess with file monitor
Starting server in PID 19573.
serving on http://gsoft-domain:5000
```

of course with resolved IP address instead of gsoft-domain. And all run well, but on the **5000** port only! When I trying to open just the website without port specified, I see my first website, served by Apache =) So how could I configure all this tangled configs to make my application work on **80** port by default. I know I could buy another static IP address and reconfigure above configs with 80 port, but I hope there is a way to run multiple Pyramid applications on the same IP.

Comment: You already have Apache using the port 80. You could use Apache as the reverse proxy instead of nginx. Setting up nginx behind Apache would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

If you install [Flup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup/1.0), then You can also configure nginx without the need to create a proxy and spawn pserve as a FastCGI process:

**production.ini**

```
[server:main]
use = egg:Flup#fcgi_thread
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5000
```

**Command**

```
 prj-env/bin/pserve --daemon --pid-file=$PID_FILE --log-file=$LOG_FILE --user=$USER --group=$GROUP production.ini start
```

**Nginx**

```
server {

server_name  gsoft-domain.com;
charset     utf-8

access_log  /root/gsoft-domain.com/logs/access.log;

location / {

fastcgi_pass   gsoft-domain;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
}
}

upstream gsoft-domain {
   server 127.0.0.1:5000;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of running application as separate process and proxying to it with nginx, you could use apache's mod_wsgi module:

http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration-guides/running-a-basic-application.html

You may follow django guide to deploy pyramid app with mod_wsgi. The difference is only in django.wsgi file. Name it myapp.wsgi and load application with pyramid.paster.loadapp:

```
from pyramid.paster import loadapp
from logging.config import fileConfig

fileConfig("/absolute/path/to/production.ini")
application = loadapp("config:/absolute/path/to/production.ini")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modwsgi/